React Native Video Playback Issues with expo-av: Videos Lag and Stop Playing When Viewable
I am working on a React Native app using Expo and the expo-av package for playing videos. I have a FlatList that renders video posts, where each video should start playing when it becomes viewable and pause when it's out of view.
Problem:

Lagging Videos: The videos sometimes take a long time to load, which affects the user experience.
Inconsistent Playback: Some videos that should be playing when they are in view either don't start playing or stop abruptly, even though they are still visible in the viewport.
Viewability Issue: I am using onViewableItemsChanged to manage which video is active and should play, but it's inconsistent in determining which video to play or pause.

Relevant Code:
Here is a simplified version of my HomeVideoFeed component:
import { View, FlatList } from "react-native";
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import VideoPost from "./VideoPost"; // This handles the video rendering

const dummyPosts = [
  { id: "1", video: "video_url_1", caption: "Post 1" },
  { id: "2", video: "video_url_2", caption: "Post 2" },
  { id: "3", video: "video_url_3", caption: "Post 3" },
];

const HomeVideoFeed = () => {
  const [activePostId, setActivePostId] = useState(dummyPosts[0].id);
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState(dummyPosts);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs = useRef([
    {
          viewabilityConfig: { itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 50 },
          onViewableItemsChanged: useCallback(({ viewableItems }) => {
            if (viewableItems.length > 0) {
          setActivePostId(viewableItems[0].item.id);
        } 
      }, []),
    },
  ]);

  return (
    <View>
  <FlatList
    data={posts}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <VideoPost post={item} activePostId={activePostId} />
    )}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
    viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs={viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs.current}
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  />
</View>
  );
};

export default HomeVideoFeed;

In my VideoPost component, I handle the video playing logic like this:
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Video } from "expo-av";
import { View, Pressable, StyleSheet, useWindowDimensions } from "react-native";

const VideoPost = ({ post, activePostId }) => {
  const video = useRef(null);
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(null);
  const { height } = useWindowDimensions();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!video.current) return;
    if (activePostId === post.id) {
  video.current.playAsync().catch((error) => console.error("Play error:", error));
} else {
  video.current.pauseAsync().catch((error) => console.error("Pause error:", error));
}
  }, [activePostId]);

  return (
    <Pressable style={{ height }}>
  <Video
    ref={video}
    source={{ uri: post.video }}
    style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
    resizeMode="cover"
    onPlaybackStatusUpdate={(status) => setStatus(status)}
    isLooping
  />
</Pressable>
  );
};

export default VideoPost;

What I've Tried:

Optimizing Viewability Config: I’ve set the itemVisiblePercentThreshold to 50%, assuming this would ensure that the videos start playing only when at least 50% of the video is visible.
Handling Active Post Playback: Using the useEffect hook in the VideoPost component to manage the playAsync and pauseAsync methods based on the activePostId.

Questions:

Why are some videos not playing even when they are fully visible?
Why do some videos stop abruptly when still visible in the viewport?
What can I do to reduce the lag time when loading and playing videos?

Any help or suggestions for improving performance and handling viewability would be appreciated!

I was playing around with your code and at first I was getting the same problems you have; but now Im not getting the playback problem. I have no idea why. I think my code is nearly identical to yours https://snack.expo.dev/tLjAsGuz7tPbu3euCjpmS

idk about reducing the lag time. If the lag is being caused by downloading bits of the video, you could use expo-asset to prefetch videos

Did it crash with you too ? The app sometimes crashes with me when on the HomeVideoFeed , I'm not able to figure out the problem , could it be becuase of the video source itself ? @phantomSpooks

I wasnt getting any crashes but I also didnt use react-navigation

Im using expo router.I'm going crazy to solve , like logic wise everything seems good , not sure where the problem lies

Im wondering if your navigator's header/bottomtab  is throwing off the measurements for the viewable detection

Have you tried setting the height in the flatlist?

Yea i have tried setting the item layout but still lagging and crashing
